# The instance's public ip does not work after creating an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) of that instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-codestar

I created a Java web application(EC2 not Beanstalk) using amazon codestar. Then I went to the instance and created an AMI while it was running. AMI was created successfully. However, this instance's public ip does not respond anymore(the web page says refused to connect). The instance is running but ip does not respond. And also after creating another instance from the image that was created, that new instance's public ip also does not work.

Comment: Did you try restarting the instance?

Comment: what is the HTTP response code that you get? Is it 503 ? Maybe you have an application issue. Could you please tell us what us the HTTP response code first and post the application's logs as well.

Comment: yes I restarted the instance too. still does not work.

Comment: @Investigator It says: This site can’t be reached. ec2-3-84-4-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
-No HTTP error response code shows up

Comment: @EshaSherry I wanted to see the application's logs in order to see if it is up and running. You should be able to retrieve these logs either from the AWS console log or by manually retrieving the logs after you connect to the EC2 through ssh: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: Are you able to ping the ip? Are you able to telnet to the host/port? That will isolate if it is an ec2/network issue or your application issue.